# Eclipse: Cant create new Android Application Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, installation, adt

I am trying to create a new `Android Application project` within `Eclipse Luna` as follows:

```
File > New > Android Application Project
```

However when I try to do so the `"Next"` Button is greyed out, i.e.:

[image]

It is important to note that I am purposely using **older** versions of the `SDK` and `ADT` (Both 21.0.0) as they as compatible with a 3rd Party plugin I wish to use.

Within my `SDK manager` I get the following screen:

[image]

Every time that I try to install the `Android SDK Platform tool`s, SDK manager states that it is installed but it never is. Could *this* be the cause of my initial problem?

**How can I solve this** and be able to create an Android Application Project?

**EDIT:**

When I try to select a `compiler` there is **nothing** in the drop down menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the SDK platform-tools to solve the empty drop-down **sub-problem**

Answer (score 0):

Select supported Compiler.

as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but please see my edit to the Question, I am unable to select a compiler